# Boolean value in radiobox in React

Tags: reactjs, boolean, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to get the value of my checkbox to dispatch my request. So here is my radiobox and I am getting the values but these are string not boolean.

```
<Form.Group className="radio">
                <Form.Label className="radio-subtitle">
                  Is it operable?{" "}
                </Form.Label>
                <div className="radio-check">
                  <Form.Check
                    type="radio"
                    label="Yes"
                    id="op-yes"
                    name="isItAvailable"
                    value="1"
                    onChange={handleChange("isItAvailable")}
                  />
                  <Form.Check
                    type="radio"
                    label="No"
                    id="op-no"
                    name="isItAvailable"
                    value="0"
                    onChange={handleChange("isItAvailable")}
                  />
                </div>
              </Form.Group>
```

So I tried to convert it to Boolean but it didnt help much. I think even 0 or 1, since there is a value every time it returns true.

```
Boolean(inputs.isItAvailable),
```

So I wonder if there is anyway to get the value in Boolean. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could let the values be 1 or 0 and use !! operator to convert them to boolean:

!!0 is false and !!1 is true

Comment: I dont think it is the answer. First in value you are not able to give a something outside of "". And if you put !! inside, it doesnt matter because it is string already

Comment: I edited my answer because it only works with integer values. if you take the value from the radio (valueFromRadio) and assign it to a constant like this: const value = !!valueFromRadio it will be a boolean with this rule: !!0 is false and !!1 is true becasue Javascrip takes a zero as a false. That's what I meant

Comment: As you are handling the changes in a method you could also pass the value for that radio: onChange={handleChange(true) for first radio and onChange={handleChange(false) for the second one.